# mac cron can't use the shell correctly

Tags: mac-osx, bash, cron

I've set up cron to run a simple hello world shell script, but it's giving me an error that Google isn't helping me resolve. I've got to be missing something really simple!

Here's my crontab:

```
MAILTO=me@domain.com
SHELL=/bin/bash
30 * * * * * $HOME/hello.sh
```

Here's hello.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                       
echo HELLO WORLD!
```

I get this error email:

```
/bin/bash: 555: command not found
```

I have tried setting shell to `/bin/sh` but it makes no difference. I still get an analogous error message.

Comment: If your question is answered, don't forget to mark a 'Best Answer!'

Answer (score 2):

cron takes 5 parameters for the timing. You've given 6 (`30` plus 5 `*`), so it's using the sixth to get the command name.

Comment: Thank you! I posted my update just as you posted your answer!